# HTML set custom validation error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to validate my input field if its a digit or not

```
<input...type="number" step="1"...>
```

This works well, but form gives the warning that input is not a valid number, while I want to show something like "Only digits allowed"

Can I customize the message? the style should be same like my other validation messages, not a different pop up or something

Comment: As a side note, don't forget server-side validation ! Client-side validation is only user-friendlyness.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands currently, the only way to do it consistently is through JavaScript, by using the `setCustomValidity()` [function](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#dom-cva-setcustomvalidity):

```
<input...type="number" step="1" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Only digits allowed')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```

Some browsers have implemented [their own custom attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation), but they aren't reliable yet.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMN6B/1/)

HTML5Rocks has done an [in-depth analysis](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) of the browser support and pitfalls for this functionality.